# Como enviar através do formulário em PHP, a opção selecionada de uma select/option do HTML5?

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função `Obtem_Todas_Meta` retorna a *query* do banco, faço associação obtenho a `id` que preciso e envio pelo formulário, mas o valor que selecionei não é enviado corretamente, pois acaba enviando o último valor e as vezes o da primeira da lista do `option`.

```
<select  name="opcaometa">
    <?php 
    $dados = Obtem_Todas_Meta();                  
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($dados)){    ?>      
        <option  value="3"><?php echo $resultado['id_met']."-".$resultado['titulo_met']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: o campo é `id_met`?

Comment: isso o campo que quero enviar é id_met  para registrar no banco

Comment: eu ainda pensei em enviar através de uma sessão //$_SESSION['id_da_meta'] = $resultado['id_met']; mas ainda assim manda o valor errado

Comment: <select name='opcaometa'>
<option value='Curso de PHP Avançado' name='Curso de PHP Avançado'>Curso de PHP Avançado</option>
</select>, se seu select estiver sendo gerado dinamicamente dessa maneira, não ocorrerá porblemas Hamilton. Se continuar sem funcionar existe problema em outra parte do código.

Comment: @HamiltonVentura editei a pergunta deixando o código mais fácil para ler e percebi que no PHP dentro do `option` há uma aspas faltando em `."-.`. Por favor, verifique no seu código original se ela existe.

Comment: sim existe, provavelmente foi na hora de eu editar o código para enviar ele ficou assim

Comment: deem uma olhada atualizei com uma imagem do banco de dados , selecionei o numero 15 como ID no option e ele enviou 14 -

Comment: `<option  value=""` aqui tem um problema cade aqui o valor?

Comment: estou testando aqui ja atualizei coloquei um valor 3. O valor que a option envia sempre é o do primeiro item da lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode passar o campo `value` em branco ou com um valor fixo, tem que passar a informação que você quer na outra página (id ou nome):

Exemplo:

```
<option value="'.$resultado['id_met'].'">'.$resultado['id_met']."-".$resultado['titulo_met'];.'</option
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo era isso mesmo, eu também tinha problema na função de banco de dados. valew

Comment: Ok! Se te ajudou aceite a resposta :)